# Can't log out/restart/shutdown via Top menu bar

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, restart, logout

When I click on Log Out, Restart or Shutdown nothing happens, but I can suspend computer.

What's wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your computer with the power button or letting your battery die. Now once restarted try it again and see if it works. If it doesnt work then try to use your other OS or if you arent dual booting just try it again

Comment: Pressing power button did the trick. Thank you.